# Escape quotation marks using Java, JSP, JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, json, jsp, escaping

I have the following JavaScript code in a JSP page

```
<script>
    var myJSVar = jQuery.parseJSON('${ aJSONStringFromJava}');
</script>
```

The parsed JSON is used to populate a html table and looks like this:

```
[{column1: "valueColumn1Row1", column2: "valueColumn2Row1"},    {column1: "valueColumn2Row1", column2: "valueColumn2Row2"}, ...]
```

In my Java code I populate the JSONObject like this:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
for(Bean bean : beans){
  jsonObject.put("colum1", bean.getColumn1());
  jsonObject.put("column2", bean.getColumn2());
}
```

Now I need to put an image in my table similar to this

```
 jsonObject.put("column1", "<img src='image.png'>");
```

However at this point I get mixed up with the quotation marks. Using single quotation marks will interfere with the ones from the JS variable declaration, double quotation marks will interfere with the ones used in the JSON.  Can anybody please tell me how I can escape the quotation marks to make this work. Thanks!

Comment: escaping `"<img src=\"image.png\">"`

Comment: This let's me escape the double quotation marks in JAva put will result in something like this in JSON: ...{column1: "<img src="image.png">", column2: "valueColumn2Row1"}...  and mix things up there

Comment: "Java" tag is really usefull? Don't think so...  Java <> JavaScript !

Answer (score 0):

What about escaping the double quotes like this:

```
"<img src=\\"image.png\\">"
```